# AMP requires async js; is there a way to have a local fallback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amp-html

Google's AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) guidelines suggest that the loading of the AMP javascript should be `async`:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to ensure a local fallback version of the javascript file is loaded, should the CDN fail to deliver?

Normally, I would add a js test immediately after the script is loaded to see if it loaded some constant (like `jQuery`). However, when `async` is used, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to determine if it will load since there's a potential race condition between the loading of the script and the test that determines if the script loaded.

Comment: I think that if the CDN fails to deliver, your client's browser has bigger issues than trying to use a fallback. CDNs by their nature need to have 99.9% uptime, or else they fail at being a CDN.

Comment: When developing offline, it's sometimes helpful to not have to depend on a CDN being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to provide a local fallback:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" onerror="document.write('<script src=\'v0.js\' async></script>')" async></script>
```

Tested in the latest Firefox.